# Understanding decision_function values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm currently in the middle of my first machine-learning and so far I don't quite get the scale of the values that I get from `decision_function(X)`(Nor how to understand them).

Based on the sklearn [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.decision_function) `decision_function(X)` is meant to:

> Predict confidence scores for samples.

Nonetheless, when running the following script:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix , precision_score, recall_score


mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

classifier = SGDClassifier(random_state = 42, max_iter = 5)


X,y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
some_digit = X[36001]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]

random_order = np.random.permutation(60000)

X_train, y_train = X_train[random_order], y_train[random_order]

y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)
y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)


classifier.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
print(classifier.decision_function([X_test[1]]))
```

it prints out `[-289809.39489525]` for the `decision_function` at this point I'm not sure how to read nor how to evaluate these values *(I was expecting to see percentages)*. If anyone could explain to me what these readings mean that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 7):

**How to get probabilities (percentages)?**

Use the `predict_proba` method.

**What is** `decision_function` **?**

Since the `SGDClassifier` is a linear model, the `decision_function` outputs a signed distance to the separating hyperplane. This number is simply <**w**,**x**> + b or translated to scikit-learn attribute names 
<`coef_`,**x**> + `intercept_`.

Comment: So how would I read the numbers? The bigger they are the more confident the answer is? for example, in this case `[-289809.39489525]` the model is more confident in the first value or second one?

Comment: You need to look at the sign. So in your case, the negative sign suggests the model predicts the sample to be from the "not a five" class. Regarding the confidence, the bigger (in absolute terms) the more confident. However, in order to arrive at the probabilities scaling via a sigmoid function needs to be performed.

Comment: oooh, so the smaller the number the nearer the prediction to the given class. in other words very small number == very confident. very big number == not so confident? Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Yes, but why to use the `decision_function` at all --- the actual value is not  normalized and not fully interpretable unless compared to other samples. You seem to be interested in the final probabilities so I would simply just use the `predict_proba`

Comment: The thing is that I'm reading a [http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920052289.do](book)  and it is talking about the `decision_function`. So I'm trying to get head around it.

Comment: For further ref you may check: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18374/predicting-probability-from-scikit-learn-svc-decision-function-with-decision-fun/18375#18375

Comment: I have just one last question is `[-289809.39489525]` two different number -289809 and 39489525 or is it one whole number -289809.39489525